# WCF error handler

Tags: wcf

I have created a web service based on

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/06/introducing-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx

i am trying to add an error hadler  based on

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFErrorHandling.aspx

I have given  
 In web.config such that i am getting 
result of a  [OperationContract]
either as xml or as Json based on the  request content type header.
But when an error occurs  the error is returned  only as XML
It is not returning error as JSON
Wat can i do to get error as JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement IErrorHandler and write a ProvideFault method to output as WebContentFormat.Json

you can get all the details of how to do it here:

http://blog.manglar.com/how-to-provide-custom-json-exceptions-from-as-wcf-service/
http://blog.wadolabs.com/2009/03/wcf-exception-handling-with-ierrorhandler/

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/97ddb118-fdfd-4651-9e61-4d822861325f

this post has helped me as such